# Socket emits data to often to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

**When using socket-io in the following way, the client gets the data too often.**

**Server.js**

```
socket.on('rcn-scd-fiv', () => {
    rcdvsf.get('rcn-scd-db').then((data) =>{
      socket.emit('int-con', data)
    })
    console.log('data given to', socket.id)
    
  })
```

**client.js:**

```
socket.emit('rcn-scd-fiv')
    socket.on('int-con', data => {
      // The data is logged 18 times to the console
      console.log(data.rcdvsf)
      setRooms(data.rcdvsf)
    })
```

**console**

Comment: Your console listing is not visible. I suggest you put more logging to the console at both ends, not just in the event handlers. Also, what does `setRooms` do?

Comment: At the client end, if you are registering the handler for 'int-con' every time you run that section of code - i.e. each time that `socket.emit(',...')` is run - then you are adding a new handler every time. So, every handler that is added will run for a single received message, so probably there are 18 handlers at the client end.

Comment: JohnRC So how can i fix this? We are not allowed to use xhr's .

Comment: @JohnRC the section of code is only run once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to use `useEffect()`. This way the function is only called once